# how convert string to a weekday in java?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a string values like "wed","mon","thu" ... I want to substract 1 day from this values. the expected output will be "tue", "sun","wed". how to achieve this in java 8?

I am able to do it for current week. But not getting it if I pass a string.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current date : " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-"
            + now.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    String[] strDays = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday",
            "Friday", "Saturday" };
    System.out.println("Current day is : " + strDays[now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1]);
```

Input : "wed","mon","thu"
Output Needed : "tue", "sun","wed"

Comment: You can use an enum for this task.

Comment: I recommend in any case that you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `DayOfWeek` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

> how convert string to a weekday in java?

Use a formatter:

```
static DateTimeFormatter dowFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("EEE")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

To parse into a day of week;

```
    String dowString = "wed";
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(dowFormatter.parse(dowString));
    System.out.println(dow);
```

This outputs:

> WEDNESDAY

The `DayOfWeek` enum represents the 7 days of the week. Once you’ve got the day of week as such an object in your code, getting the previous day is trivial (when you know how):

```
    DayOfWeek currentDow = dow.minus(1);
    System.out.println("Current day is : " + currentDow);
```

> Current day is : TUESDAY

It does work for all days of the week; when we hit the beginning of the week (Monday in this enum declaration), the subtraction goes back to the end of the week (Sunday).

If you want, you may format the enum instance back to a string for display using the formatter from the top:

```
    String currentDowString = dowFormatter.format(currentDow);
    System.out.println("Current day is : " + currentDowString);
```

> Current day is : Tue

There is no reason for hardcoding the names of the days in your own code. Java already knows the names and the common abbreviations in many languages.

There is also no reason why you should want to use the `Calendar` class, neither in this nor in other cases. It doesn’t really fit your use case. And it was always poorly designed and is now long outdated. Instead use java.time, the modern Java date and time API to which `DayOfWeek` belongs, for all you date and time work.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)